# SVN restore from a backup

Tags: svn, centos, tortoisesvn, backup

I used ftp to copy all files folders which were on a svn server I pulled these off via ftp just copy them on to my external hard drive thinking I can access the files like normal but I cannot all I have is hooks, db, conf etc rev folder which are large but the files are all numbered.

How do I get to the svn data files of my projects?

trying to view them on my windows machine on my external hard drive.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a copy from server files. So, this structure (`hooks`, `db`, etc.) is correct.

To obtain your repository files, you should use the `Export` command from `TortoiseSVN`, or simply copy-and-paste your repository from the client.

If you don't have this client repository, I suggest you to boot another SVN Server and restore this backup on it.